# Load explicit entity (not entities extending it) with EF

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-6, discriminator, tph

We've got a code first approach in our application. We have a simple hierarchy similar to this:

SuperSpecializedPerson extends SpecializedPerson extends (abstract) Person

We've got two repositories for SuperSpecializedPerson and SpecializedPerson.
When querying for SuperSpecializedPerson, the returned entities are the wanted ones. 
When querying for SpecializedPerson, all SpecializedPerson as well as SuperSpecializedPerson (as an instances of SpecializedPerson) are being returned. This is my issue.

Checking the SQL query is see this part of code `WHERE ([Extent1].[Discriminator] IN (N''SuperSpecializedPerson '',N''SpecializedPerson''))`, where I'd like to have `WHERE ([Extent1].[Discriminator] IN (N''SpecializedPerson''))`.

How can I get only SpecializedPerson?

[edit] I'll give some more context to my issue to figure out if I am on the wrong track altogether:
I have to return a list of DTOs of the same type from the backend to the frontend. The DTOs are being created with Automapper according to the specified mapping profiles.
First I query for SuperSpecializedPerson, map them to DTO, then the same happens for SpecializedPerson and concatenate both lists. After merging, I get two instances of all SuperSpecializedPerson (once with only the SpecializedPerson properties).
The described model has been defined according to the current knowledge and will probably in future to have a second class extending  SpecializedPerson.

Comment: Have you tried using C#'s [is](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/is) keyword?

Comment: I have, but SuperSpecializedPerson is SpecializedPerson as it extends it

Comment: You shouldn't be testing if they are a SpecializedPerson, you should be testing if they are **not a SuperSpecializedPerson**.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This happens because `SuperSpecializedPerson` is also a `SpecializedPerson`. This a fundamental aspect of inheritance. A cat is an animal. The keyword `is` includes derived types.

Query with

```
context.SpecializedPersons.Where(p => !(p is SuperSpecializedPerson));
```

Another approach not as performing as this one but also working with additional derived types in future, is to filter with LINQ-to-Objects

```
context.SpecializedPersons
    .Where(p => /* other filters go here */)
    .AsEnumerable() // Switches to LINQ to Objects
    .Where(p => p.GetType() == typeof(SpecializedPerson));
```

Your edit says that the problem is the mapping with automapper. See automapper documentation for [Mapping Inheritance](http://docs.automapper.org/en/stable/Mapping-inheritance.html). Especially the part with [Runtime polymorphism](http://docs.automapper.org/en/stable/Mapping-inheritance.html#runtime-polymorphism).

Comment: Thanks, this actually works! But isn't there a more restrictive solution to request a single type of an entity. This is a maintenance nightmare, as the modfel will evolve

Comment: @Philippe: If that is what you need, you're somewhat misusing inheritance. The point of inheritance is the guarantee that every `DerivedClass` is inherently also a valid `BaseClass`. Therefore, expecting "a single type of an entity" doesn't make sense, as all derived classes are inherently also a valid object of that "single (base) type". You're looking for the entities that are not a derived type, which can only be reached by testing that these entities are not any of the derived types (hence Olivier's answer, which is the correct approach).

Comment: @Philippe: Your way of approaching inheritance comes dangerously close to violating the [Liskov Substitution Principle](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/703634/SOLID-architecture-principles-using-simple-Csharp). Codewise, when dealing with `BaseClass` objects, you should not be worrying about whether they are actually a `DerivedClass` or not. If you treat a `BaseClass` differently if it happens to also be a `DerivedClass`, then your data model is flawed.

Comment: Maybe your `SuperSpecializedPerson` should be a `SpecializedPerson2` directly deriving from `Person` instead.

Comment: I've edited the initial post to give some more context.

Comment: @Philippe: In response to your update: if you already have a list of `SuperSpecializedPerson`, then it should be easy to remove the same people from the list of `SpecializedPerson`. Or, even easier, how about simply retrieving the full unfiltered list of `SpecializedPerson`, and then splitting that list into the two needed DTO lists? Saves you a trip to the DB.

Comment: @OlivierJacot-Descombes I don't see Automapper at cause. We use its inheritance with include. The issue is that we get two instances of SuperSpecializedPerson; once as SuperSpecializedPerson and once as SpecializedPerson

Comment: @Flater That's right, I can easily filter them out in code. I expected to have a possibility to influence this on DB level. I don't see a way to do this with a single query though. If querying for SuperSpecializedPerson, I'll only get those. If querying for SpecializedPerson, I get all entries, but not the specialized properties of SuperSpecializedPerson.

Comment: @Philippe: `I expected to have a possibility to influence this on DB level` Look at Olivier's initial answer. That filtering should occur on the DB level. In SQL, you're then asking the database to exclude SpecializedPeople that also exist in a different table (SuperSpecializedPeople). This obviously requires you to refer to the SuperSpecializedPeople table by name. If multiple derivations exist, then you must refer to all of them in order to have them all excluded.

Comment: You get 2 instances because you make two queries on different entities. You should be able to query only once and get a single list. Shouldn't you only have a single repository for `Person`? See: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/mvc/overview/getting-started/getting-started-with-ef-using-mvc/implementing-inheritance-with-the-entity-framework-in-an-asp-net-mvc-application

Comment: @Philippe: We're going in circles here. Your expectation does not match reality. **Implicitly**, EF includes derivations of a base class, due to the design philosophy behind inheritance. If you want to exclude these derivations, then you'll need to **explicitly** request EF which derived types to exclude. There is no way to change how EF implicitly interprets inheritance.

Comment: Thanks for your help, I've found a satisfactory solution by including a property describing the original entity.